# Usability or performance requirement?

Tags: requirements, non-functional

Usability requirements are focused on User interfaces, how easy they are to learn, how quick access to some frequent menu options are provided, etc. Suppose we have the following requirement:

```
 The system should show menu options after user login within 1 second.
```

What type of Non Functional Requirements is this? A performance requirement or usability? Thanks

Comment: This question is definitely not a duplicate of the indicated question. I am asking about the difference between two types of Non Functional Req

Comment: It is both a "performance" requirement *and* a "usability" requirement.  How quickly the menu options are shown affects usability.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the requirement into two

1. The system should show menu options
2. Time to Interaction on all Pages/Screens should be < 1 sec

The first is a Feature requirement, the second is a 'Definition of Done'  or 'Quality Expectation' requirement that would apply to all stories